# How to set zendFramework application public folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

my structure of webserver:

```
mysite.com/www/here goes zendFramework folders and files..
```

i want to make my url like this

```
mysite.com
```

but, not like this:

```
mysite.com/public/
```

so how to make it the best way?, using .htaccess redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this article : http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-on-a-shared-host/

in index.php in the root folder:

```
<?php 
define('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT', true);
include 'public/index.php';
```

in .htaccess file in the root folder:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```